# Is it possible to add a glyph icon to html select in twitter bootstrap framework?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know how to add glyph icon to html input element in twitter bootstrap framework. Example could be found here http://techieninjas.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/52.jpg (envelope icon near input field)

My question is - is it possible to add the same glyph icon to html select instead of input ?  If so, could you please provide an example ? Thanks !

Comment: Actually, if you look at the source (http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/), the icon isn't a pseudo element of the input tag, but part of the `span` that precedes it.  The before/after pseudo elements don't work like you expect on input elements.

Comment: it is actually an `<I>` tag, `<i class="icon-envelope"></i>`, and that goes for the most, unfortunately not `<option>` (as always, TB does not change the rules of HTML)

Comment: Thanks ! Also, I have found this issue https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3831 - input-prepend doesn't works with select :(

Comment: I was wrong, we have solved this problem by using fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome and        <div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-globe"></i>         </span>....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have more luck with using select2: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Also, this is available as a Kickstrap app <del>http://getkickstrap.com/apps/permalink/select-2-52238/</del>

**UPDATE**

Kickstrap 2 now uses RequireJS functionality to load apps, making it more cross-functional. In K2, Select2 can either be loaded as you would on any other html doc, or via [System.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

[GetKickstrap.com](http://getkickstrap.com)

Comment: Thanks, I really like this Select2 component!